# OpenLayers 3 get mouse coordinates on select interaction

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to get the coordinates of the mouse click that the select interaction is responding to. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectInteraction.on('select', function(evt) {
    console.info(evt.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate);
});
```

Always, `console.info(evt)` to see if there's something there.